# Shared folder not giving prompt for user info

Tags: networking, dns, file-sharing, shared-directory

I am setting up a shared folder that needs to have users for different levels of access.
The way I did this in windows 10 is I shared the folder on a system and and added several users on the system.
When I connect to it from client systems I get a prompt to enter a username and password.
Now when I do it at my friends I dont get that prompt and instead I get an error that I dont have permission.
Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

removing the home share
using the net use command to delete all connections
adding the folder via map network drive
Deleting the folder that used the "everyone" permission temporarily while I was sorting stuff out
that did it :)